# Encrypt file using node js and decrypt file in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Am new to Encrypt and Decrypt the file

Here am trying to encrypting csv file (client side encryption) and pushed into s3 bucket with expect metadata then I am trying to decrypt (push) csv file from s3 bucket to redshift using PostgreSQL copy command but its throwing **bad encrypt** Error

I know This is actually a common issue when users are encrypting in one language and decrypting in another but I am expecting result of this.

Here is my code

**NodeJs**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var sharedSecret = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("base64"); 
var initializationVector = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64"); 
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('AES256', sharedSecret,initializationVector);

var input = fs.createReadStream('file.csv');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('fileEncrypt.csv');

input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);

output.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Encrypted file written to disk!');
});
```

**Redshift Copycommand**

```
COPY  objects.encrypteddata (Date,Device, Start) 
FROM  's3://fakepath/fileEncrypt.csv' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>;master_symmetric_key=<master_Key>'
delimiter ',' encrypted CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 MAXERROR 1000COMPUPDATE ON;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: Failed writing body (0 != 453) Cause: error:06065064:
       digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Welcome exact solution